# How to decrement a number in each filename in a directory?

Tags: bash, sed

Running "ls -lrt" on my terminal I get a large list that looks something like this:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 pratik  staff   1849089 Jun 23 12:24 cam13-vid.webm
-rw-r--r--  1 pratik  staff   1850653 Jun 23 12:24 cam12-vid.webm
-rw-r--r--  1 pratik  staff   1839110 Jun 23 12:24 cam11-vid.webm
-rw-r--r--  1 pratik  staff   1848520 Jun 23 12:24 cam10-vid.webm
-rw-r--r--  1 pratik  staff   1839122 Jun 23 12:24 cam1-vid.webm
```

I have only shown part of it above as a sample.

I would like to rename all the files to have a number one less than current.

For example,

```
mv cam1-vid.webm cam0-vid.webm
mv cam2-vid.webm cam1-vid.webm
.....
....
mv cam 200-vid.webm cam199-vid.webm
```

How can this be done using a os x / linux bash script (perhaps using sed) ?

Comment: Why do you want to use sed?

Comment: There's a perl `rename` script in CPAN that can do this.

Comment: You realize `sed` is for editing files and does not necessarily act upon the file names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with plain bash:

```
for i in {1..200}
do
    mv "cam${i}-vid.webm" "cam$((i-1))-vid.webm"
done
```

Comment: This could be dangerous. Due to locale-dependent collating sequencing, you may end up processing `cam10-vid.webm` before you get to `cam9-vid.webm`, which will overwrite the latter... The general idea's good, but I think it needs some numeric sorting to generate the file list instead of a plain `for file in ...`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `find`, split up the file names, to find the number, subtract one, and rename:

```
find . -name "cam*-vid.webm" -print0 | while read -d\$0 old_name
do
    number=${old_name#cam}        #Filter left to remove 'cam' prefix
    number=${number%-vid.webm"}   #Filter right to remove '-vid.webm' suffix
    $((number -= 1))
    new_name="cam${number}-vid.webm"
    echo "mv \"$old_name\" \"$new_name\""
done | tee results
```

This will merely print out the commands (that is why I have `echo`). I'm piping it into a file named `results`. Once this command completes, look at `results` and make sure it does everything it should. Whenever there's an operation like this, there can be a nasty surprise. For example, if I rename `cam02-vid.webm` to `cam01-vid.webm` before I rename `cam01-vid.webm`, I am going to overwrite `cam01-vid-webm`.

Maybe a safer way is to explicitly give the file numbers I need:

```
for number in {1..200}
do
    $((old_number = $number + 1))
    echo mv "\"cam${old_number}-vid.webm\" \"cam${number}-vid.webm\""
done | tee results
```

**Useful hint**: If the `result` file looks good, you can actually just run it as a shell script:

```
 $ bash results
```

Another possibility is to test to make sure the old file exist:

```
for number in {1..200}
do
    $((old_number = $number + 1))
    if [ -f "$cam${old_number}-vid.webm" ]
    then
        echo mv "\"cam${old_number}-vid.webm\" \"cam${number}-vid.webm\""
    else
        echo "ERROR: Can't find a file called 'cam${old_number}-vid.webm'"
    fi
done | tee results
```

Answer (score 0):

A [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) solution.

First it traverses all input files (`@ARGV`) and filters those that are plain files and not links (`grep`), extracts the number (`map`) and sorts numerically in ascendant to avoid overwritting (`sort`). Later creates a new file decrementing the number and renames the original:

```
perl -e '
    for ( 
        sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } 
        map { m/(\d+)/; [$1, $_ ] } 
        grep { -f $_ && ! -l $_ } 
        @ARGV 
    ) {
        $n = --$_-> [0];

        ($newname = $_->[1]) =~ s/\A(?i)(cam)\d+(.*)\z/$1$n$2/;
        print "Executing command ===> rename $_->[1], $newname\n";
        rename $_->[1], $newname;
}' *
```

Assuming initial content of the directory as:

```
cam1-vid.webm
cam13-vid.webm
cam12-vid.webm
cam11-vid.webm
cam10-vid.webm
cam2-vid.webm
```

After running the command yields:

```
cam0-vid.webm
cam10-vid.webm
cam11-vid.webm
cam12-vid.webm
cam1-vid.webm
cam9-vid.webm
```